# psexec - The specified network name is no longer available

Tags: remote-access, psexec

i'm stuck right now on executing psexec to a target machine and getting below error.

```
psexec \\ABC -u DOMAIN\user -p **** cmd /c ipconfig /all

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Couldn't access ABC:
The specified network name is no longer available.
```

I verified below item worked.

1. I can access \\ABC\admin$
2. pslist \\ABC - works
3. I have admin rights on source and target machine
4. I can successfully login into the machine
5. nslookup resolves the domain name
6. telnet ABC 445/135 works
7. Workstation, Server and computer browser services running

Any idea what else need to be check?

Comment: Experiencing identical symptoms - worth noting that if ABC is an invalid hostname, it instead says "The network path was not found" instead.

Comment: Also does it do it if you connect via IP and not system name?

Comment: @GeneMoody-Action1 correct - domain name, FQDN, or IP yields the same results. Nslookup works fine, as does pslist. I can RDP and SMB into the system(s) I tried.

Comment: Interesting, does it work to another station from that one (Connect to same source different target) and from another (different source same target)?  And have you eliminated firewall on both sides as a cause, there is more going on than just the share.

Comment: Thanks @GeneMoody-Action1 - I haven't ruled out firewall (or group policy/registry) yet. I've been able to use PsExec on another system in another environment successfully, just haven't been able to find a difference between the two setups. Previously, this worked for me in both environments. This is in a corporate landscape, so I am not the only one administering it.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that psexec would fail but pslist would not. Does pslist truly work, and if so, what is the specific command being used?

Comment: @wrieedx `pslist.exe \\hostname` works whereas `PsExec.exe \\hostname cmd /c whoami` does not - even ran back to back in the same admin CMD prompt with both executables in the same folder.

Comment: it is possible some anitvirus or antimalware is catching it on the remote host? PsExec is used pretty extensively in exploitation. So though not malicious inherently, its function is leveraged in a lot of attack scenarios and some live malicious code packages it for this purpose as well. It may be that it is reporting this error *in error* because it is being interrupted at some critical step and it is the best it could come up with as to why?

Comment: @GeneMoody-Action1 it's *possible* but unlikely at this stage, as we've gone as far as (temporarily) disabling antivirus software to see if that was the culprit. It may be worth noting that the test fails instantly - it doesn't wait for a reply (or it gets it instantly). I haven't verified whether anything gets to the target server at all, but considering I get different results if I attempt to target an invalid IP or an accessible server on a different domain, the problem may be on the target ends.

Comment: Does there happen to be any VPN or firewall devices between? What is source/target OS? Not sure *yet* what  would be looking for there, but running out of ideas. :/

Comment: @GeneMoody-Action1 no VPN, but there is a firewall. Both source and target are Windows Server 2016. When I send a single request, I do see 8 trios of 4672, 4624, and 4634 events on the target system (24 events total). None of them indicate any form of failure. Additionally, the Windows Firewall log shows the communication over tcp/445 without anything being dropped. Checking with our firewall team to see if there's any other traffic getting blocked in this timeframe.

Comment: Makes me wonder of something inbeween may be intercepting such as inflight malware scanner. it *may* be the service executable specifically, which explains why pslist works. if you check the error level after execution, it may shed light on it.  Also what happens if you try a simple command such as "echo 1 > c:\file.txt" which would tell you if it was even executing on the other side at all and help narrow it down?

Comment: @GeneMoody-Action1 I believe we may have found the culprit - tcp/445 communication *for psexec* was being blocked - which is to say, the source would send a handshake to the target (which I saw in the event log), that would succeed, and following the handshake, the psexec application would send its request and the network firewall would block that as it was not a whitelisted application. We have positive evidence of that. I couldn't say why pslist works - perhaps it doesn't pass an "application" to the firewall, and if it does, it may be permitted. Will update as we test our exception.

Comment: I would support that, the nature of psexec is it moves the service executable, then uses RPC to execute commands, to start it and the connection comes back as a second connection originating on the responder side. pslist is just executing a command. So the return path is likely an established connection from the initiator side. So that makes perfect sense. This is an interesting problem, and I would very much like to know how it turns out for my own knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem (see comments on original question).

The solution was that while the network firewall was permitting tcp/445, it was *blocking* tcp/445 specifically for the appid "psexec". Once an exception was made (as minimal as possible - remember, psexec is dangerous to allow), I was able to execute PsExec successfully.